# Count minutes with TimeStamp from MAC first appearence to Last

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to count the time a specific device (MAC) stays in the area from its TimeStamp for each day. So my table is:

```
TimeStamp             MAC                 ID
2021-04-02 08:55:03   3F:1A:54:EC:56:2D   1
2021-04-02 09:05:11   15:A0:B7:26:4F:5C   2
2021-04-02 08:41:49   15:A0:B7:26:4F:5C   2
2021-04-02 08:53:20   3F:1A:54:EC:56:2D   1
2021-04-02 08:36:35   3F:1A:54:EC:56:2D   1
```

And I want to return something like this (Minutes 19,14):

```
Minutes  MAC                  ID  DATE
19       3F:1A:54:EC:56:2D    1   2021-04-02
14       15:A0:B7:26:4F:5C    2   2021-04-02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by MAC/ID and date and then take the time elapsed in minutes:

```sql
SELECT
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(TimeStamp), MAX(TimeStamp)) AS Minutes,
    MAC,
    ID,
    DATE(TimeStamp) AS DATE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    MAC,
    ID,
    DATE(TimeStamp);
```